# How share of files from downloads folder android 11

Tags: java, android, kotlin, security, android-intent

Help me please, how can I share of content from downloads folder in android 11 after downloading of file. When I try to do this, any app can't use my file. I haven't any fileprovider and any tag queries, which used in Android 11. I haven't any example, how to use FileProvider for downloads folder. Thanks everybody for any help.

## ActivityMain.kt

```
package ru.alexandrkozlovskiy.KtIssue

import android.Manifest
import android.app.DownloadManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

    class ActivityMain : AppCompatActivity() {
private var loadId:Long=-1
        private lateinit var dM:DownloadManager
    private val loadReciever:
            BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action.equals(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)) {
val i:Intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,dM.getUriForDownloadedFile(loadId))
                i.type="image/jpg"
                //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) (with this line we have crash)
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION)
                startActivity(i)
            }
        }
    }
        val linkUri:Uri=Uri.parse("http://cron.me.fo/cron2/tmpimg_new/news_pic_093aa62ed3b0967f59c7464fec5ec9ec-re.jpg")
    fun loadUrl(uri: Uri) {
        val request: DownloadManager.Request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,uri.lastPathSegment)
        loadId = dM.enqueue(request)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        dM=applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        registerReceiver(loadReciever, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),1)
else loadUrl(linkUri)
    }

        override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode: Int,
            permissions: Array<out String>,
            grantResults: IntArray
        ) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
            if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) loadUrl(linkUri)
        }

        override fun onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(loadReciever)
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

## app.kt

```
package ru.alexandrkozlovskiy.KtIssue

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.PrintStream

class app:Application() {
inner class ExceptionCatcher(var handler: Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler):Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

        override fun uncaughtException(p0: Thread, p1: Throwable) {
var info:String
try {
val p:PackageInfo = applicationContext!!.packageManager!!.getPackageInfo(
    applicationContext!!.packageName,
    0
)!!
    info ="version: ${p.versionName} version code: ${if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.P)p.versionCode else p.longVersionCode}\n"
}
catch (e: Exception) {
    info ="version: 1.2 version code: 2\n"
}
            info+="version of android ${Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}\n"
val outputStream:ByteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
p1.printStackTrace(PrintStream(outputStream))
            info+="thread ${p0.toString()} and problems are:\n${outputStream.toString()}"
val i:Intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"))
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("k.sasha1994@yandex.ru"))
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "crash of loader app")
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, info)
i.flags=Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
try {
startActivity(i)
    //handler.uncaughtException(p0,p1)
    System.exit(0)
}
catch (e: Exception) {
//Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Не удалось отправить лог: Ошибка ${e.message}",1).show()
    handler.uncaughtException(p0, e)
}
            }
}
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
if(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() !is ExceptionCatcher) Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(ExceptionCatcher(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()))
}

    override fun onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate()
    }
}
```

## AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="ru.alexandrkozlovskiy.KtIssue">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
            android:name=".app"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/binoculars"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
                android:name=".ActivityMain"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I reported issue to

Comment: I reported an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190787890.